# JDBC - prepareStatement - How should I use it?

Tags: prepared-statement

I saw this example somewhere:

```
 rs = connection.prepareStatement("select * from table").executeQuery();
```

Could I use this format, if I want to execute a query like this "**Select * from table where column = "hello"** "?

The way in which I usual I use prepareStatement object is something like this:

```
        String sql = "select * from adresa where column = ?";
        PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pre.setString(1, i);
        rs = pre.executeQuery();
```

Later Edit:

I don't understand. Pascal Thivent wrote that I can use the short version with In parameters, but Liu tells me this is not possible. :) Anw, using Pascal's version, i receive this error: **void cannot be dereferenced**

Comment: I've deleted my answer, it was just wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the first form if there are no bind variables (question marks) in the query. It's just a shortened version of what you posted.

Also, if you use the shortened form you won't have the opportunity to reuse the PreparedStatement object.

Comment: I don't understand. 
Pascal Thivent wrote that I can use the short version with In parameters, but you tell me this is not possible. :)

Anw, using Pascal's version, i receive this error: void cannot be dereferenced

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial example how to use this interface:

```
static final String USER = "root";
            static final String PASS = "newpass";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, USER, PASS);

            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement
            String query = " insert into students (ID, last_name, first_name, birthday, hometown)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, 808027);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, "Davis");
            preparedStmt.setString(3, "Felicita");
            preparedStmt.setDate(4, startDate);
            preparedStmt.setString(5, "Venice");

            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.execute();

            conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

of course u can use a string variable for the query in which u put in ur dynamic data and run it.

rs = connection.prepareStatement(variable).executeQuery();

Comment: also if u want to do the dynamic replacing urself why not use 'statement' and executeUpdate()

Comment: statement has different performance characteristics than prepared statement.

Comment: @ken .. yes i always forget that one .. thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

The long form is often, but prepared statements can be precompiled by the db, and if used properly will help prevent sql injection.

```
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
 conn = getConn();
 ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from x where y = ? "); //note no sb.append()'s or +'s, to helps prevent sql injection
 ps.setLong(1, 12l);
 rs = ps.executeQuery();

 while (rs.next()) {
 ... act ...
 }
} catch ( Exception e) {
} finally {
 if (rs != null) rs.close(); 
 if (ps != null) ps.close();
 if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
```

Who said java was verbose. :)